# Parse netdata json output (mulltiple arrays) with jq

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I'm trying to use jq to combine two arrays and running into a bit of trouble.

I'm attempting to parse out the data from netdata (netdata.firehol.org) and the two pieces of data within the json response that I"m interested in are both part of an array. The first array is labels for the datapoints in the second array.

**Sample Input**

```
[
  "time",
  "guest_nice", 
  "guest",
  "steal",
  "softirq",
  "irq",
  "user",
  "system",
  "nice",
  "iowait"
]
[
  1460728600,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0.45731,
  0,
  0.25108,
  11.74702,
  48.22465,
  0
]
```

**Input**

If you want to grab fresh data yourself to test against, you can use the following:

```
curl -s -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 
'http://netdata.firehol.org/api/v1/data?chart=system.cpu&after=-10&before=0&points=1&group=average&format=json&options=seconds%2Cjsonwrap' | jq '.result.labels, .result.data[]'
```

I've tried to use map() as well as trying to assign vars to both arrays and then print out the objects together, but have been unsuccessful (below).

**Code**

```
 | jq '.result.labels as $labels | .result.data[] as $data | .result.data[] | Label: $labels[.], data: $data[.]}'
```

I appreciate anyone's insight in advance as I'm a little stuck, and would prefer to be able to do this all in jq rather than using for loops in bash (if possible).

**Expected Ouput**

{
      "time": "1460728600",
      "guest_nice": "0",
      ...
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified exactly how you want the arrays to be combined, but one approach is to use `transpose`, which in this case is effectively a kind of `zip`.  For example:

```
$ jq -n -c '[["a","b"], [1,2]] | transpose'
```

yields: `[["a",1],["b",2]]`

If you wanted an array of objects, then with the same input,

```
transpose | map( { (.[0]) : .[1] } )
```

would yield: `[{"a":1},{"b":2}]`

If your jq does not have `transpose`, here is its definition:

```
# transpose a possibly jagged matrix, quickly;
# rows are padded with nulls so the result is always rectangular.
def transpose:
  [range(0; (map(length) | max)) as $j 
   | [range(0; length) as $i | .[$i][$j] ] ] ;
```

Alternatively, if you would prefer a very brief `zip`:

```
def zip: [range(0; .[0]|length) as $i | [.[0][$i], .[1][$i]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that handles the general case where the first array contains the key names and the following arrays contain values using **transpose** and **from_entries**

```
  {h:.[0], v:.[1:][]}                        # {h:[keys], v:[values]}
| [.h, .v]                                   # [ [keys], [values] ] ...
| [ transpose[] | {key:.[0], value:.[1]} ]   # [ {"key":key, "value":value}, ... ]
| from_entries                               # { key:value, key:value, ... }
```

For example, if this filter is in `filter.jq` and `data.json` contains

```
["time","guest_nice","guest","steal","softirq","irq","user","system","nice","iowait"]
[1460728600,0,0,0,0.45731,0,0.25108,11.74702,48.22465,0]
[1460728601,0,0,0,0.45732,0,0.25109,12.74703,49,0]
```

then the command

```
jq -M -s -c -f filter.jq data.json
```

produces

```
{"time":1460728600,"guest_nice":0,"guest":0,"steal":0,"softirq":0.45731,"irq":0,"user":0.25108,"system":11.74702,"nice":48.22465,"iowait":0}
{"time":1460728601,"guest_nice":0,"guest":0,"steal":0,"softirq":0.45732,"irq":0,"user":0.25109,"system":12.74703,"nice":49,"iowait":0}
```